# socket.io split emit and listener to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
const msgSocket = id => {
  const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3002')
  socket.emit('sendMsg', {
    userId: id
  })

  socket.on('recieveMsg', msg => {
    console.log('x,', msg)
  })
}
```

I'm able to run above function, but how to get the value of the msgSocket?

eg I run `msgSocket(2)` elsewhere and I want to get the `msg` I tried

```
 return socket.on('recieveMsg', msg => {
     return msg
 })

 const msg = msgSocket(2)
 console.log('msg: ', msg)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: means there's no where to split it to another function? I have complicated business logic it's not good to mix around connection protocol, imagine one day the protocol change..

Comment: @JackBashford what is the reason to add ecmascript-6 tag?